# VBA Excel: Get the clicked cell´s adress on another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file A with a macro and I have to retrive a cell´s adress in another excel file B by the user´s click on it.

The macro looks like this.

In the **Class**:

```
Public WithEvents appevent As Application

Private Sub appevent_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
ClickedCell = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

In the **Module**

```
Sub ClickedCellSub()
Dim WbA As Variant, WbB As Variant
WbA = ThisWorkbook.Name
WbB = "B.xlsx"
MsgBox "Please double click on the Assembly SS 00 you want to compare"
Set myobject.appevent = Application
Workbooks(WbB).Sheets(1).Activate
Set myobject.appevent = Nothing
MsgBox ClickedCell
Workbooks(WbA).Activate
End Sub
```

The problem is, the macro doesn´t wait for the event DoubleClick on the other excel sheet and goes to the end.

How can I stop the macro until the event happens?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: An onclick event works on the current workbook. So you would have to make it that it then exports something to a different workbook.

Comment: "Could you give me some suggestion? I´ll be then glad to post the complete code." - that's not how this site works, it's the other way around.

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to use Excels record macro facility, switch it on then do what you want by hand, when your complete stop recording the macro and copy the macro code.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us something

Comment: In another workbook in the same Excel-application? Then just use Withevents ... as Application

Answer (score 0):

I would use event sinking, but not sure how you have approached it, but this is how i'd use.

In a class use the following :

```
Private WithEvents wb As Excel.Workbook
Private rng As Excel.Range

Public Event evtCellClicked(rngClicked As Excel.Range)
Public Event evtCellDoubleClicked(rngDoubleCliecked As Excel.Range)

Public Sub init(wbInput As Excel.Workbook)
    Set wb = wbInput
End Sub

Public Property Get CellClicked() As Excel.Range
    CellClicked = rng
End Property

Private Sub wb_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Set rng = Target
    RaiseEvent evtCellClicked(Target)
End Sub

Private Sub wb_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Set rng = Target
    RaiseEvent evtCellClicked(Target)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code. In the module:

```
enter Option Explicit
Private mobjApplication As clsApplication
Global ClickedCell As String

Sub Vergleichen()
Dim StruktBer As Variant        


StruktBer = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Strukturbericht öffnen")                       '####Name der Datei aus der Strukturberich

Set mobjApplication = New clsApplication
Workbooks.Open StruktBer

MsgBox "Bitte die Sachnummer der Strukturstufe '00' anklicken die man vergleichen möchte"

End Sub

Sub GOFURTHER
```

In the Class:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mobjApplication As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set mobjApplication = Application
End Sub

Private Sub mobjApplication_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ClickedCell = Target.Address
    Set mobjApplication = Nothing
    Call GOFURTHER

End Sub
```

The macro stops until the user clicks on the other excel table. Is there any way not to exit the first sub and to remain in the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply using an InputBox ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox
In your prompt you ask the user to select a range in the appropriate document, and that's it.